# PHP syntax problems with drop down list selected value

Tags: php

I am trying to populate a drop-down list with a selected value based on a variable, since I am completely new in PHP I do not even know if what I am trying to do is right, any advice will be greatly appreciated. The whole code is encased in a select, I already have a previous if statement and it works just fine

```
<!--verif si editoin -->
<?php if($EditResto == true): ?> 
    <option value = "">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT ProvinceNameFR FROM Province ORDER BY ProvinceNameFR";
        $sqlresult =  sqlsrv_query($GLOBALS["dbcon"], $sql);
            while ($sqlrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {
            $row1 = $sqlrow["ProvinceNameFR"];
                <option value = "" <?php if ($row1 == $resto_province_value) echo 'selected';?>> $resto_province_value </option>;           
        ?>
    </option>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: You are definitely missing a `?>` after setting `$row1`. From a style standpoint, code like this that switches in and out of php is hard to read and maintain. Consider using `print` to output text from within your php loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php if($EditResto == true):
$sql = "SELECT ProvinceNameFR FROM Province ORDER BY ProvinceNameFR";
$sqlresult =  sqlsrv_query($GLOBALS["dbcon"], $sql);
while ($sqlrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {
$row1 = $sqlrow["ProvinceNameFR"];
?>
<option value = "" <?php if($row1 == $resto_province_value) 
echo 'selected';?>><?php echo $resto_province_value?></option> 
<?php }?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: working good. thanks

Answer (score 1):

While fixing that `?>` ending tag will fix your syntax error, this is how I would write the code so it would be easier to read in my opinion.

```
<!--verif si editoin -->
<?php 
if($EditResto == true){
    $sql = "SELECT ProvinceNameFR FROM Province ORDER BY ProvinceNameFR";
    $sqlresult =  sqlsrv_query($GLOBALS["dbcon"], $sql);

    // Print Default Option
    print '<select>'; 

    while ($sqlrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {
        $row1 = $sqlrow["ProvinceNameFR"];
        $optionHTML = '<option value = ""'; 
        if ($row1 == $resto_province_value) {
            $optionHTML .= ' selected';
        }
        $optionHTML .= '>' . $resto_province_value . '</option>';
        print $optionHTML;

    } 
    print '</select>';
}
```

You probably want to set the `name=""` attribute on the html select element and the `value=""` attribute of the options.